# Oracle Select with if some column not found return null value to that column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a select query in oracle if select column not found return null with out error message.

select A, B, C from tbl;
but table just have A,C column only

Comment: You can use [the information_schema views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/columns-table.html) to see which columns a table has

Comment: @Andomar: these *information_schemas* are probably SQL server specific and don't have anything to do with Oracle.

Comment: @Jayanath don't you think it's easier to just write `select A, C from tbl` instead of going an esoteric route to solve this "problem"?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query for your question:

```
SELECT Decode (a, 0, NULL,
                  a) a,
       Decode (b, 0, NULL,
                  b) b,
       Decode (c, 0, NULL,
                  c) c
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT Count (*)
                FROM   user_tab_cols
                WHERE  table_name = 'ABC'
                       AND column_name = 'A') a,
               (SELECT Count (*)
                FROM   user_tab_cols
                WHERE  table_name = 'ABC'
                       AND column_name = 'B') b,
               (SELECT Count (*)
                FROM   user_tab_cols
                WHERE  table_name = 'ABC'
                       AND column_name = 'C') c
        FROM   abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
SELECT b.*, DECODE (a.a, 0, NULL, decode(a.b,0,null, decode(a.c,0,null))) missing_col
FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT ( * )
              FROM user_tab_cols
             WHERE table_name = 'ABC' AND column_name = 'A')
              a, (SELECT COUNT ( * )
                    FROM user_tab_cols
                   WHERE table_name = 'ABC' AND column_name = 'B')
                    b, (SELECT COUNT ( * )
                          FROM user_tab_cols
                         WHERE table_name = 'ABC' AND column_name = 'C')
                          c
      FROM abc) a, abc b
      where a.rowid = b.rowid;
```

Showing result like this below:

```
A          C          MISSING_COL
---------- ---------- -----------
a1         c1                    
a2         c2
```

2 rows selected.

You can treat MISSING_COL as your unavailable column.